# Call existing stored procedure from another stored procedure with table valued parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

**Goal**: Call the existing stored procedure many times with different sets of values, e.g. Parameter 1 {100000, 100001, 100002....}, ....

`dbo.ExistingStoredProc` = existing stored procedure that takes 2 parameters {int, varchar(20)}

I use table valued parameters for this task. However, it's a real mess to modify the existing stored procedure to replace the two parameters with one table valued parameter. So I thought about creating another stored procedure with table valued parameter then call the existing stored procedure. **Is this possible?**

`dbo.CallingStoredProc` = stored procedure with table valued parameter and calls `dbo.ExistingStoredProc`

`dbo.CallingStoredProc` (simplified to 1 parameter)

```
@TvpParameter tvpMyType READONLY

Declare @sn int

Select @sn = SerialNumber from @TvpParameter

EXEC dbo.ExistingStoredProc @sn
```

Modified script that executes `dbo.CallingStoredProc`

```
DECLARE @TvpParameter AS dbo.tvpMyType

INSERT INTO @TvpParameter (SerialNumber)    VALUES (123456), (654321)

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = dbo.CallingStoredProc           
@tvpExistingPar = @TvpParameter

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

RESULT

I only get the result for the last item in TVP, which is SerialNumber = 654321.

Comment: Using a cursor would make sense for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Using `TVP` they way you are using, does not have any advantage at all. It is not any better than `while loop` or `cursor` approach. You should modify `ExistingStoredProc` to handle `TVP`

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. You may struggle to identify "last item" - but that is a very different question.

Comment: I have two choices to achieve my goal. 1) Write an "adapter" stored procedure that calls the existing stored procedure 2) Modify ExistingStoredProc to handle TVP per @Squirrel's suggestion.

I went with option #2 because option #1 is only viable if it is trivial. Since I've already struggled with option #1 (@SMor) and can't easily see how cursor can help make CallingStoredProc work (@ZLK) then I went ahead and rewrote ExistingStoredProc. Problem solved! I tried to avoid the painful rewrite but couldn't. Thanks for the input fellas!